# Could not start Docker image "testcontainers/ryuk" on Windows 11

Tags: docker

I'm trying to start container from `testcontainers/ryuk:latest` image.
The error is:

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is
> the docker daemon running?

Windows:
Edition Windows 11 Pro,
Version 22H2,
OS build    22621.1413.

Docker version: 4.17.0

Settings of Docker:

> Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS == true
>
> Use the WSL 2 based engine == true

Resources -> WSL integration settings:
[image]

I can start `docker/getting-started` image. But what is the problem with `testcontainers/ryuk` image ?

Comment: As shown here, you need to map the docker socket to the container when you run it. Do you do that? https://hub.docker.com/r/testcontainers/ryuk You probably need to modify the command from what's shown for WSL though.